# span hover did not work

Tags: html, css

span hover did not work.I wanna make a system  that when I set mouse in File Select1& File Select2& File Select3,the letter become blue.
I wrote in html

```
<form action="/accounts/upload_save/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg file_select">
                    File Select1
                    <input type="file" name="image">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg file_select">
                    File Select2
                    <input type="file" name="image2">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>
          　　
          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg file_select">
                    File Select3
                    <input type="file" name="image3">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">
              </div>
          </form>
```

I wrote in css file

```
.file_select:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But now,it did not work.I did not think the way of writing is wrong.But what should I fix this?Am I wrong to write background-color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of text, 
`color: blue,` property is used in CSS, not `background-color` property

Check this example, is this what you mean?

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/L65qysey/)